# Apache Ivy: Resolve dependency using a pattern

Tags: ant, ivy

I want to download artifacts using ivy:resolve, but using a pattern that uses the [conf] attribute. So I have defined the following in 
**IvySettings.xml**

```
<caches defaultCacheDir="${env.IvyLib}\cache" artifactPattern="[conf]\[artifact].[ext]" checkUpToDate="false" />
```

Notice the pattern

```
artifactPattern="[conf]\[artifact].[ext]"
```

, so I want to resolve the dependencies and place them in a folder as per their configuration. I have defined the following configuration in
**Ivy.xml**

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="ConfGroup1" description="First group of dependencies"/>
    <conf name="ConfGroup2" description="Second group of dependencies"/>
</configurations>
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="derby-db" name="derby-db" rev="10.2.2.0" conf="ConfGroup1->default">
        <artifact name="derby-db" type="zip" ext="zip" />
    </dependency>
    <dependency org="derby-db" name="derby-db" rev="10.4.1.3" conf="ConfGroup2->default">
        <artifact name="derby-db" type="zip" ext="zip" />
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now the dependencies get resolved fine, but only 1 folder gets created for configuration: **default**. No folder is being created for ConfGroup1 & ConfGroup2 configurations. How can I be able to create multiple folders as per my defined configurations during resolve?

P.S., I know this can be achieved using ivy:retrieve, but I do not want to use it, because it will involve copying artifacts from ivy cache to another place after ivy:resolve, and I have multi-gigabyte worth of artifacts. Copying them separately will create additional overhead during the build, which I cannot afford due to the project requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The ivy [retrieve task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) has a symlinks option, that can be used to conserve space.

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── ivysettings.xml
├── ivy.xml
└── target
    ├── ivy-reports
    │   ├── ivy-report.css
    │   ├── myorg-mymod-ConfGroup1.html
    │   └── myorg-mymod-ConfGroup2.html
    └── lib
        ├── ConfGroup1
        │   └── db-derby-10.12.1.1.zip -> /home/mark/.ivy2/cache/db-derby/db-derby/zips/db-derby-10.12.1.1.zip
        └── ConfGroup2
            └── db-derby-10.11.1.1.zip -> /home/mark/.ivy2/cache/db-derby/db-derby/zips/db-derby-10.11.1.1.zip
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <property name="build.dir" location="target"/>

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:resolve/>

        <ivy:report todir='${build.dir}/ivy-reports' graph='false' xml='false'/>

        <ivy:retrieve pattern='${build.dir}/lib/[conf]/[module]-[revision].[ext]' symlink="true"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="myorg" module="mymod"/>

  <configurations>
    <conf name="ConfGroup1" description="First group of dependencies"/>
    <conf name="ConfGroup2" description="Second group of dependencies"/>
  </configurations>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="db-derby" name="db-derby" rev="10.12.1.1" conf="ConfGroup1->default">
        <artifact name="db-derby" type="zip" ext="zip" />
    </dependency>
    <dependency org="db-derby" name="db-derby" rev="10.11.1.1" conf="ConfGroup2->default">
        <artifact name="db-derby" type="zip" ext="zip" />
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
  <resolvers>
    <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true" />
    <url name="db-derby">
      <artifact pattern="http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist//db/derby/[module]-[revision]/[module]-[revision]-bin.[ext]"/>
    </url>
  </resolvers>
  <modules>
    <module organisation="db-derby" resolver="db-derby" />
  </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried with and without symlink several times, it turns out that with symlink=true takes more time with retrieve than symlink=false. For me, time is the constraint here. Also, I am using windows, and in both the cases, I see that the artifacts in ivy cache and the retrieve directory have the same size. Will they still have the same size?

Secondly, retrieve is the only way to have the zip files copied? So in my example, IvySettings.xml is not able to pick up the user defined configurations and is loaded before Ivy.xml, hence the reason it is not able to pick up the configs?

Comment: @WaqasShah The windows OS does not support symbolic links.

Comment: Okay. So I guess the bottomline is to use ivy:retrieve anyways then? The method that I was trying initially cannot be made to work?

Comment: @WaqasShah What I think you were trying to do is configure a cache locally within the workspace. The would not be a normal usecase, the purpose of caches is to optimize downloads, making it easier to use tasks like retrieve. I understand your desire to optimize the handling of large files, which is what the symbolic links feature is designed solve.... Unfortunately in your case Java will copy "linked" files, because it's a concept not supported by the underlying OS.

Comment: @MarkOConnor: Yes I wanted to directly resolve dependencies which are separated in folders by an artifactPattern using a [conf] wildcard. Now it looks like the only way I have, is to resolve them and then retrieve them.